# Understanding an Inequality In a Paper

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, regression, symmetric-matrices

The paper is the following:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.06412.pdf

Right above (5) on page 5, the first inequality of the line where they use lemma 8, I'm not quite sure I see how they are using lemma 8.

Lemma 8:
Given $d$-dimensional square diagonal matrix $D$ and arbitrary square $d$ dimensional matrix $M$,
$\max_i \min_j |\sigma_i(D) - \sigma_j(M)| \leq ||D-M||_{op}$

The inequality in question is

$||(I + B_j(\Sigma + \lambda I)^{-1})^{-1}||_{op} \leq \frac{1}{1 - \frac{||B_j||_{op}}{\lambda}}$

where $B_j = -(X_j X_j^T + \lambda I)/n$ and $\Sigma = X^T X /n $ where $X$ is just some arbitrary $n \times d$ data matrix.

I assume lemma 7 is also useful:

$||(M + \lambda I)||_{op} \leq 1/\lambda$

From my guess, they just applied the inverse of lemma 8, however that means that there is an issue with norm of the inverse vs inverse of the norm which I can't resolve (the inequality between norm inverse and inverse norm goes the wrong direction). Then they use submultiplicative property of norm along with lemma 7 to get the rough form of the RHS. I'm just not sure how lemma 8 is exactly applied because of this issue. Am I missing some matrix identity? Possibly woodbury?

Comment: $XX^T$ is a matrix, $X^TX$ is a number

Comment: I had interpreted X_j to be a horizontal vector, but yeah I think the paper meant vertical. I'm pretty sure on the actual dimensions of things so I'm not too confused about that part. However as a full matrix $X^T X$ is definitely not a number. you mean to add a subscript right

Comment: I mean assuming the $X_j$'s are vectors in which case $X_j^TX_j=X_j \cdot X_j$

Comment: ok yeah, I think we are agreeing. I'm just going to delete the part about that then since it's distracting from my main question.

Comment: It looks to me like $\  X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n\ $ are meant to be $\ d\times1\ $ column vectors (they're given as being in $\ \mathcal{X}\subset\mathbb{R}^d\ $), and $\ X\ $ is  the $\ n\times d\ $ matrix whose $\ i^\text{th}\ $  row is $\ X_i^T\ $. If this is correct, then $\ X,X^T,XX^T,\ $ and $\ X^TX\ $ would be $\ n\times d, d\times n, n\times n\ $ and $\ d\times d\ $ matrices, respectively. That's the only way I'm able to make sense of the definition and identity $$\widehat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{n}X^TX=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_iX_i^T$$ towards the top of page 4.

Comment: Yes I agree, thanks. The dimensions are quite clear now (and not quite the focus of my question)